# ajax request for related model with ember-data

Tags: ember-data

say i have the models custom_route and user. to get the data for the routes that belong to the user ajax requests that look like "/users/:user_id/routes" have to be send to the server. now .. how do i get ember-data to send these get requests?

When i setup the specific route related to this request like this:

> App.UserCustomRoutesRoute = Em.Route.extend({
>           model: function() {
>
> ```
>         return this.store.find('user_custom_route');      });
> ```

... the request is just '/user_custom_route'

i took a look at the transition cheat sheet for beta 1 (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md) but it didn't really help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Update below**

I found a solution but I don't know if it is really the way to go. First I setup the route with a findQuery call:

```
App.UserCustomRoutesRoute = Em.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
            return this.store.find('user_custom_route', {user_id: this.controllerFor('user').get('user_id')});
        }
});
```

Then I hooked into the adapter methods which configure the get request (findQuery and buildUrl).

```
App.UserCustomRouteAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        buildURL: function(type, id) {

            return 'users/' + id + '/routes';
        },
        findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
            return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, query.user_id), 'GET');
        }
    });
```

Setup like this the request has the form of 'users/:user_id/routes'.

**Update**

I had to change the model method of the `App.UserCustomRoutesRoute`. Most of the times `user_id` at `App.UserController` isn't yet set when `App.UserCustomRoutesRoute` is called (p.e. when a user enters the site via its related address ('url#/users/:user_id/custom_routes'). So I had to put a authentication check which replies the `user_id` if successful before the call to the related store.

```
 App.UserCustomRoutesRoute = Em.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
            var self = this;
            console.log('user custom routes route');
            return Em.$.get('loggedIn').then(function(promise) {
                return self.store.find('user_custom_route', {user_id: promise.user_id});
            });
        } 
});
```